# Facebook troubles using visual web developer 2010

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm sorry if this is the 100 post you see on this topic, but I could't find one that is helping so far.

I'm trying to simple project on Visual Web Developer 2010 express That logs in to a given user name in facebook and enters a status for him(2 text boxes for user name and password and another one for the text to be the status, and a button to start)

i can't find a way to do so without creating a facebook app and using the app_id and facebook personal plugins for login..

can someone give me help on the subject? code samplesm or something that i can implement now, this small project is for a job review i have in 2 days

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on this but...

I would make a facebook app for this.

You could also search the page and find an element using jQuery. Im not sure if the id of the controls on the textbox change that much.

Again. Not sure. Just some guesses. You can find valuable information on the facebook api here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

This is another alternative that is probably the right approach. Can you provide more details?

Comment: i have a facebook app and i was able to create a small website that by clicking a button, a plug-in of facebook apeares and let you post something on your wall, but i didn't write any of that, it was completly a jsScript by facebook - and that is not the point

Comment: What is the final goal. To have a window into facebook to update your status that is on another website?

Comment: something like that.
to be more accuarate - the final goal is to be able to use an external website to log in with any user and post a status, without using facebook already written code(which is usually in PHP or JS anyway)